# AWS. Write data from S3 to Elasticsearch through Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a question related to Glue. My current task it read data from S3 and write it to Elastisearch (on AWS). And I have to use Glue. Glue is supported read from S3 as source, but cannot use Elasticsearch as target. My question how can I write data from Glue to Elasticsearch with the least effort?

Comment: Why do you **have to** use Glue if Glue doesn't support ES as a target and you need to write to ES?

Comment: Have you checked [AWS Glue Elastic Views](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/features/elastic-views/), otherwise you have to use S3 to store aws-glue output and from S3 you can load data into Elasticsearch [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-aws-integrations.html#es-aws-integrations-s3-lambda-es]

Answer (score 0):

If you **must use glue**, You can simply leverage glue to write python code without leveraging spark. Configure a new job with the "type" as "python shell". Writing python code, you can now leverage boto3 library to access your files in S3:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

After retrieving the you want to upload to elastic search, you can then use a post request to upload the document to elastic search:

```
r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=document, headers=headers)
```

Please see AWS documentation below in the **Loading streaming Data into Amazon ES from Amazon S3** Section.
["Loading Streaming Data into Amazon Elasticsearch Service"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-aws-integrations.html#es-aws-integrations-s3-lambda-es)